# How to use declare a function template pointer typedef without specifying template?

Tags: c++, function, templates, function-pointers, function-templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;



enum Op{ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MATMUL};

template <typename dtype>
using AlgoFunction = double(*)(const vector<dtype> &, Op);

// for example, the sum function doesn't require template.
// just write sum(a), not sum<float>(a)
template <typename dtype>
double sum(vector<dtype> inputs) {
    dtype summer = inputs[0];
    for (int i=1; i<inputs.size(); i++) summer = summer + inputs[i];
    return double(summer);
}

// i need to do ask this question because I perform the same
// algorithm (linearAlgo, ...) on different types of data
// (dtype = float, double, matrix<float>, matrix<double>, ...
template <typename dtype>
inline dtype numOperate(const dtype &a, const dtype &b, Op op) {
    if (op==ADD) return a + b;
    if (op==SUB) return a - b;
    if (op==MUL) return a * b;
    if (op==DIV) return a / b;
}


template <typename dtype>
double linearAlgo(const vector<dtype> &inputs, Op op) {
    dtype summer = inputs[0];
    for (int i=1; i<inputs.size(); i++) summer = numOperate(summer, inputs[i], op);
    return double(summer);
}

template <typename dtype>
double reverseLinearAlgo(const vector<dtype> &inputs, Op op) {
    int n = inputs.size();
    dtype summer = inputs[n-1];
    for (int i=n-2; i>=0; i--) summer = numOperate(summer, inputs[i], op);
    return double(summer);
}

template<typename dtype>
vector<double> run(vector<dtype> inputs, Op op, double (*func)(const vector<dtype>&, Op)) {
    vector<double> res;
    res.push_back(func(inputs, op));
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<float> a;
    vector<double> b;
    a.push_back(1); a.push_back(2); a.push_back(3);
    b.push_back(1); b.push_back(2); b.push_back(3);

    vector<double> res = run(a, ADD, linearAlgo);  // allowed without specifying template
    vector<double> resf = run(b, ADD, linearAlgo); // still work with multiple data type


    // I want to do this assignment without specifying the template.
    // in the above linear, linearAlgo (no specifying template) is possible, why not here ?
    AlgoFunction<float> functor = reverseLinearAlgo; // works, but I don't want it
    //AlgoFunction functor = reverseLinearAlgo;   // I want to do this. compile error
    vector<double> res2 = run(a, ADD, functor);

    cout << res[0] << "\n";
    cout << res2[0];
    return 0;
}
```

So I have a function template pointer

```
template <typename dtype>
using AlgoFunction = double(*)(const vector<dtype> &, Op);
```

that points to functions like this

```
template <typename dtype>
double linearAlgo(const vector<dtype> &inputs, Op op) {
    dtype summer = inputs[0];
    for (int i=1; i<inputs.size(); i++) summer = numOperate(summer, inputs[i], op);
    return double(summer);
}
```

I know that using a template function pointer without specifying template is possible. For example:

```
 vector<float> a;
 a.push_back(1); a.push_back(2); a.push_back(3);    
 vector<double> res = run(a, ADD, linearAlgo); // allowed without specifying template
```

But then if I declare a variable of type `AlgoFunction`, the compiler force me to specify the template.

```
//AlgoFunction<float> functor = reverseLinearAlgo; // works, but I don't want it
AlgoFunction functor = reverseLinearAlgo;   // I want to do this. compile error
```

This is not good because I have many types of data `dtype`, and I don't want to specify the template again for each one.

So how can I declare `AlgoFunction functor;` instead of `AlgoFunction<some_datatype_name> functor;` ?

Thank you.

Edit: the goal is to have a `vector<AlgoFunction> functors` instead of `vector<AlgoFunction<data_type> >`. Since in the example, `res`, and `resf` both can be calculated without specifying the template for the 3rd parameter, I want to know if `vector<AlgoFunction>` is possible or not.

Comment: "So I have a function template pointer" - Or do you have an alias? `AlgoFunction` is not an instance - it does not point.

Comment: "_the compiler force me to specify the template_" - yes, you made `AlgoFunction` a convienience alias for `template <typename dtype> double(*)(const vector<dtype> &, Op);` - and the compiler wants to know the particuar instance you'd like.

Comment: "_So how can I declare `AlgoFunction functor`; instead of `<AlgoFunction<some_datatype_name> functor;`?_"  - way beyond me. As far as I know, class/function templates do not manifest themselves as instances unless called upon doing so.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, it is true that I use alias. But you can see in the example that I did not need to specify the template when passing the function as parameter for it to work. So I'm looking for a way to do that everywhere.

Comment: Be aware that resulting code might be much slower that if you are not careful. For example, a pointer to a function could be slower that an inlined function. Also it might be useful to considerate STL algorithms like `accumulate`.

Comment: @Phil1970 how about a pointer to an inlined function ? does that increase speed? If not, how much slower are we talking about? Could you give me a small benchmark ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. I suspect the confusion stems from missing the difference between a "function" and a "function template".

To explain why your first example worked, first let's examine what is actually happening when you do `run(a, ADD, linearAlgo);`. As a reminder, we have:

```cpp
template <typename dtype>
using AlgoFunction = double(*)(const std::vector<dtype>&, Op);

template <typename dtype>
std::vector<double> run(const std::vector<dtype>&, Op, 
                        double(*)(const std::vector<dtype>&, Op));
```

Equivalently, we could have had the following:

```
std::vector<double> run(const std::vector<dtype>&, Op, AlgoFunction<dtype>);
```

since `AlgoFunction` is just an alias.

Now, when we do this:

```
std::vector<double> a;
run(a, ADD, linearAlgo);
```

we know that the first argument to `run`, `std::vector<dtype>`, is `std::vector<double>`, and hence `dtype` is `double`. We can't determine anything about `dtype` from the third argument since `linearAlgo` is just a template, a "pattern".

Since we know that `dtype` must be `double`, we can choose and instantiate `linearAlgo<dtype>` – that is, `linearAlgo<double>` – as our function since that fits our signature, and everything is OK.

---

Now, what does that have to do with this?

```
AlgoFunction functor = reverseLinearAlgo;
```

In this case, we're trying to create a variable. `reverseLinearAlgo` is just a function template, not an actual function, and we don't have any other context to determine what type `functor` actually is. Hence the compiler error.

Moreover, what would this actually mean? Would `functor` have a different type depending on where you used it? If I did `auto x = functor;`, what type would `x` have? If I did something like

```cpp
AlgoFunction functor = reverseLinearAlgo;
if (test) {
  std::vector<float> x;
  functor(x, ADD);
} else {
  std::vector<double> x;
  functor(x, ADD);
}
```

would that mean that `functor` has dynamic type? This isn't something that works with C++'s (static) type system, and it can quickly get out of hand if this was made legal. This is the case with your wish for `std::vector<AlgoFunction>`: you have to store a concrete type. Otherwise the program will need to dynamically instantiate a function based on runtime information: template parameters must be known at compile time.

---

One possible alternative, if you know the types ahead of time, is to use a `std::variant` of the possible types you might instantiate with. That is, something like

```cpp
std::vector<std::variant<AlgoFunction<float>, AlgoFunction<double>>>;
```

if each element of the vector should provide one or the other, or else use

```cpp
std::vector<std::tuple<AlgoFunction<float>, AlgoFunction<double>>>;
```

if each element of the vector should be usable with either type.

Whether this is useful, and worth the added complexity, is up to you.

Comment: I never used C++17 before so std::variant is completely new to me. That's actually what I'm looking for because I know the types ahead of time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do what you want, but it is messy to implement in C++ because you have to do manual type checking if you want to seriously implement something like this.

Here is a quick method to do what you want, but beware that you need more than this to make something useful for serious work, and it's extremely easy to shoot yourself in the foot with this kind of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct AlgoFunction {
    virtual double operator()(void *) = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct AF_Sum : public AlgoFunction {
    virtual double operator()(void * inputVec) {
        T res = T();
        vector<T>* pInput = (vector<T>*)inputVec;
        for (int i = 0; i < pInput->size(); ++i) {
            res += (*pInput)[i];
        }

        return (double) res;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct AF_Mean : public AlgoFunction {
    virtual double operator()(void * inputVec) {
        T res = T();
        vector<T>* pInput = (vector<T>*)inputVec;
        for (int i = 0; i < pInput->size(); ++i) {
            res += (*pInput)[i];
        }

        return (double) res / (double)pInput->size();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vF{0.2, 0.3, 0.8};
    std::vector<int> vI{2, 5, 7};

    std::vector<AlgoFunction*> algoFunctions;

    algoFunctions.push_back(new AF_Sum<float>);
    algoFunctions.push_back(new AF_Mean<int>);

    cout << (*algoFunctions[0])(&vF) << endl;
    cout << (*algoFunctions[1])(&vI) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I didn't bother cleaning the heap-allocated memory (via new) and I didn't implement all of your functions; just a quick and dirty example of a potential solution.